# Getting the error “duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac$zza.class” when trying to build APK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi i am trying to build APK but iam Facing this problem in Android Studio.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac$zza.class

Here Is My gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someId"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



}

dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0'
}
```

And Here is My gradle (project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: try using Go to Build-->>Clean Project and then Rebuild Project

Comment: same problem bro

Comment: then try to use updated versions of all libraries you are using. May be it will solve your issue. you can detect older libraries by seeing yellow lines on that.

Comment: no thing again man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that there is conflict in gcm play services different versions it leads  to duplicate entires

Remove this from your build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0'
```

Add this

```
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

Comment: It's okay :) nice that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line in bottom of you build.gradle(app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

in build.gradle(project)

Comment: stay calm buddy.

Comment: attach your build.gradle(project) file.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me after trying for hours, this will invalidate caches and rebuilt the project on the next startup in android studio

> File > invalidated caches/restart.